# Certain CSS-class stopped working in FF, but still works in Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, browser

I hope that I'm with this question not overstepping the boundaries of this forum, but I believe that it's within the scope, albeit it's not "code-related"

I'm developing a web application that utilizes CSS for styling. I found yesterday that one part of the GUI looked weird, namely a search panel with an input field and a button. The panel had lost all CSS preferences; paddings, borders and background-colour. I had not changed anything in the class, so I was very surprised by this. I deleted, as I many times have had to do, the cookie for localhost to force re-reading of the stylesheet. However this did not help.

Since I had no idea of what could be wrong, for some reason I decided to try the application in Chrome, instead of Firefox which I always run. And the weird thing is that in Chrome it looks just fine, the way it's supposed to look and the way it looked in Firefox until yesterday. It's the same web application that's running in the browsers, same code and the same URL. Still in Firefox it totally ignores the part of the stylesheet that affects the search panel. All other instances of the GUI seems to be ok, I haven't found anything wrong.

If you recognize this problem from own experience or have heard of it and know of something I can try to do to fix it, other than erasing the cookies (which I've already tried), then please respond! Thanks!

**EDIT:** After the wishes to see the code I realized that it's rather two CSS-classes that are ignored, they visually appear very similarly so that's why I didn't notice it before.

```
.m2m-table-action-bar {
    background-color: #C9C9C9;
    border-top: 1px solid #949494;
    border-left: 1px solid #949494;
    border-right: 1px solid #949494;
}

.m2m-top-button-panel {
    background-color: #C9C9C9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #949494;
    border-top: 1px solid #949494;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Without any code, we can only guess. Have you cleared your cache? Does the page display correctly in a new firefox profile? What does the inspector say?

Comment: Have you also tried deleting the browser cache too? I agree with Rob though, it's difficult to help with out seeing some code, or a link etc.

Comment: @RobW and Gr3mlin, thank you both. It was the cache that was causing the problem. I've only bothered with removing cookies before and not the cache. The person who formulates an answer with this solution first takes the pot. Thank you again.

Comment: Just for future reference, it's probably worth noting that cookies tend to store information about your browsing sessions, like pages visited and user preferences. Where as cache stores images and html pages etc, to speed up load times and cut down on bandwidth usage. If you're having trouble with a page not picking up the changes in your style sheets it's probably best to clear the cache first.

Comment: @Gr3mlin Thanks! What a bonus! I've never made that connection actually. Still very new with web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is probably storing a cached version of the site. Try deleting the cache and then refreshing the page.